# Will mongoose add the __v properties to objects automatically if it doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know that mongoose automatically increments the `__v` property in a MongoDB to keep a track of versions. But we have a 3rd party software that writes to our database without using mongoose. It uses direct MongoDB statements. But thus it does not set the `__v` property in the database.

My question is: When manipulating a data object, will mongoose automatically add the `__v` property to an object in the database if none is set?

Comment: Which kind of manipulation? creating? updating?

Comment: By default mongoose will set _v property to your model and for every updation of record inside a collection , _v property is incremented.
If you want to disable the _v property, use { _v: false } while defining your schema.

Comment: @Mansuro Both creating and updating. Would mongoose add the __v property for creating & updating?

Comment: @beingsrv Thank you for the information but it's not really the point of my question. I know if a collection get's created over a mongoose model that the __v property is automatically created. But my question was what happens if it gets created externally without __v

Will mongoose then add the __v property itself?